# Select node values and select the max value

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I would like to select the "highest" Depth, Width and Height value from all Detail tags for each "temp" product.

Here is my XML example:

```
    <root>
     <Temp>
        <Code>1234567</Code>
            <Detail>
                <Depth>12.7</Depth>
                <Width>1.27</Width>
                <Height>15.24</Height>
            </Detail>

        <DetailConversion>
            <Detail>
                <Depth>34.925</Depth>
                <Width>30.48</Width>
                <Height>19.05</Height>
            </Detail>
        </DetailConversion>

        <DetailConversion>
            <Detail>
                <Depth>34.925</Depth>
                <Width>30.48</Width>
                <Height>19.05</Height>
            </Detail>
        </DetailConversion>
     </Temp>
<Temp>
        <Code>1234567</Code>
            <Detail>
                <Depth>12.7</Depth>
                <Width>1.27</Width>
                <Height>15.24</Height>
            </Detail>

        <DetailConversion>
            <Detail>
                <Depth>34.925</Depth>
                <Width>30.48</Width>
                <Height>19.05</Height>
            </Detail>
        </DetailConversion>

        <DetailConversion>
            <Detail>
                <Depth>34.925</Depth>
                <Width>30.48</Width>
                <Height>19.05</Height>
            </Detail>
        </DetailConversion>
     </Temp>
    </root>
```

I have tryed it with

```
int maxDepth = doc.Root.Elements().Max(x => (int)x.Element("Depth"));
int maxWidth = doc.Root.Elements().Max(x => (int)x.Element("Width"));
int maxHeight = doc.Root.Elements().Max(x => (int)x.Element("Height"));
```

But i have realy no iea why this not works, the maxDepth is always 0.
The maxDepth...must be selcted for each  , not for all together

Do you have any ideas ?

**Update complete XML**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XmlInterchange xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.edi.com.au/EnterpriseService/" Version="1" >
    <InterchangeInfo>
        <Date>2015-05-29T14:17:45</Date>
    </InterchangeInfo>
    <Payload>
        <Temporaer>
            <Temp>
                <TempCode>ST66676EU</TempCode>
                <DetailConversion>
                    <Depth>12.7</Depth>
                    <Width>1.27</Width>
                    <Height>15.24</Height>
                </DetailConversion>
                <DetailConversions>
                    <DetailConversion>

                            <Depth>16.51</Depth>
                            <Width>13.97</Width>
                            <Height>6.35</Height>

                    </DetailConversion>
                    <DetailConversion>

                            <Depth>34.925</Depth>
                            <Width>30.48</Width>
                            <Height>19.05</Height>

                    </DetailConversion>
                </DetailConversions>
            </Temp>
        </Temporaer>
    </Payload>
</XmlInterchange>
```

Comment: You are trying to cast numbers that have decimals into `int`. You should use `decimal`, `float` or `double`

Comment: This new XML is not valid, there is a closing `</RelatedOrganisations>` out of nowhere.

Comment: Could you also mark as answer the answer that actually works? Or update your question  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your codes always return `0` because there is no `Depth`/`Width`/`Height` that is *direct child* of `<Temp>`. To get max depth, max width, and max height from each `<Temp>` element, you can try this way :

```
var result = doc.Root
                .Elements()
                .Select(o => new
                {
                    maxDepth = o.Descendants("Depth").Max(x => (double)x),
                    maxWidth = o.Descendants("Width").Max(x => (double)x),
                    maxHeight = o.Descendants("Height").Max(x => (double)x)
                })
                .ToList();
```

`result` variable will be a list of anonymous objects with each object carries information of maximum values of each `Temp`.

**UPDATE :**

Your actual XML has *default namespace*. You can use combination of `XNamespace`+`"element name"` to select element in namespace :

```
XNamespace d = "http://www.edi.com.au/EnterpriseService/";
var result = doc.Root
                .Descendants(d+"Temp")
                .Select(o => new
                {
                    maxDepth = o.Descendants(d+"Depth").Max(x => (double?)x),
                    maxWidth = o.Descendants(d+"Width").Max(x => (double?)x),
                    maxHeight = o.Descendants(d+"Height").Max(x => (double?)x)
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks that should work but for my xml comes everytime a "Sequence contains no elements" exception, i will update the XML and show the complete, one moment please

Comment: You can change `(double)` to `(double?)` so that when current `Temp` element doesn't have any `Depth` for example,  corresponding `maxDepth` property will simply be `null`

Comment: I have update the  XML example in the main post, all max values are null :-/

Comment: Now it's a namespace issue, please have a look at my answer.

Comment: Why is this now a namespace issue ?

Comment: As I mention above, your xml has *default namespace*. Default namespace applied implicitly to all child elements, unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `Descendant()` which will get all child nodes of the root, as `Elements()` do not go get nested child nodes:

```
int maxDepth = doc.Root.Descendants().Max(x => (int)x.Element("Depth"));
```

or more precise will be:

```
int maxDepth = doc.Root.Descendants("Detail").Max(x => (int)x.Element("Depth")));
```

### Update:

you want to get each `Temp` node max Depth elements value, then you have to do this way:

```
var maxDepth = doc.Root.Descendants("Detail")
                       .Select(x=>x.Max(y => (int)y.Element("Depth")));
```

or:

```
var maxDepth = doc.Root.Descendants("Temp")
                       .Select(x=>x.Descendants("Detail"))
                       .Select(x=>x.Max(y => (int)y.Element("Depth")));
```

Comment: The Problem is that there could be more then one <Temp> </Temp> width the Details, will this work too ?

Comment: Yes it will fetch all child nodes

Comment: The maxDepth etc. must be selected for each <Temp> element, not for all together

Comment: You can then `foreach` into `doc.Root.Descendants("Temp")` then do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.edi.com.au/EnterpriseService/";

foreach (var tmp in doc.Descendants(ns + "Temp"))
{
  var maxDepth = tmp.Descendants(ns + "DimensionDetails").Max(x => (decimal)x.Element(ns + "Depth"));
  Console.WriteLine(maxDepth);
}
```

Or if you want all results as a sequence:

```
var a = doc.Descendants(ns + "Temp")
  .Select(e => e.Descendants(ns + "DimensionDetails").Max(x => (decimal)x.Element(ns + "Depth")));
```